# REACT New state item not being passed to sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a state with 3 prefilled entries in my App.js.  I made a component which let's a user add a new entry and add it to the state.

I have an additional component where I can look into the details of the entry in a separate page.

So App.js has the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: [
        {
          "id" : 0,
          "title":  "Entry 1",
          "content": "Nonsense, nonsense, nonsense."
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title":  "Entry 2",
          "content": "More nonsense."
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title":  "Entry 3",
          "content": "Even More Nonsense"
        }
      ],
      nextArticleId : 3
    }
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
  }
  handleSave(article) {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    const newArticle = {...article, id: this.state.nextArticleId};
    return {
      nextArticleId: prevState.nextArticleId+1,
      articles : [...this.state.articles, newArticle]
    }
  })
}
  render(){
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        <Header />
        <Route exact path="/" component={(props)=> <ArticleList {...props} articles={this.state.articles}/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/article/:id' render={(props) => <ArticleView {...props} articles={this.state.articles} />}/>
        <Route path='/create' component={(props)=> <ArticleMaker {...props} articles={this.state.articles} onSave={this.handleSave} />}/>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

and then i passed the state to the articleMaker component which saves the data into the state after it's submitted. The list then shows the new entry, but as soon as I click the new entry I get an error for the title and content for being undefined:

```
class ArticleView extends Component {
  render() {
      let {id} = (this.props.match.params);
      id = Number(id);
      let Article = this.props.articles.filter((matcher) => (
        matcher.id === id
      ))
      let {title, content} = Article[0];
    return(
      <div className="container">
      <div>{title} {content}</div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ArticleView;
```

Comment: Have you tried `render` instead of `component` in Route?

Comment: @devserkan, just tried it, didn't change anything.  What's the difference between render and component in this case?

Comment: In react-router 4.x to pass props to the components render is being used instead of component. See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5391#issuecomment-319165762